Trying to install pygraphviz, and get an error related to "building wheel"
I get an error when installing pygraphviz on a Windows 11 Pro ver 22 H2 and build 22621.2283 machine:
    C:\Windows\System32>pip install pygraphviz  
    Collecting pygraphviz  
      Using cached pygraphviz-1.14.tar.gz (106 kB)  
      Installing build dependencies ... done  
      Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
    Building wheels for collected packages: pygraphviz
      Building wheel for pygraphviz (pyproject.toml) ... error

>  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
>  × Building wheel for pygraphviz (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.  
> │ exit code: 1  
> ╰─> [48 lines of output]  
>     running bdist_wheel  
>     running build  
>     running build_py  
>     creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz  
>     copying pygraphviz\agraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz  
>     copying pygraphviz\graphviz.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz  
      copying pygraphviz\scraper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\testing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_attribute_defaults.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_clear.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_close.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_drawing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_edge_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_graph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_html.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_layout.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_node_attributes.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_readwrite.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_repr_mimebundle.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_scraper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_string.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_subgraph.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\test_unicode.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      copying pygraphviz\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz\tests
      running egg_info
      writing pygraphviz.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to pygraphviz.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to pygraphviz.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.swg'
      warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'doc'
      warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'doc'
      warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'doc'
      warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'doc'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'pygraphviz.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying pygraphviz\graphviz.i -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      copying pygraphviz\graphviz_wrap.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\pygraphviz
      running build_ext
      building 'pygraphviz._graphviz' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pygraphviz)

I tried the following:

Installed Visual C++ Studio from Microsoft (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/)
Followed the directions to install PygraphViz on Windows manually  from (https://pygraphviz.github.io/documentation/stable/install.html#windows-install). I did not use Chocolatey, I did it manually.


Please use proper formatting and include enough information to help others assist you

Hi Nol4635, I am missing your point, can you kindly guide me on the proper format...new on this :-)

I've helped you format your errors. You can use WSL to resolve this. See my answer.

Installing PyGraphviz requires:

Python (version 3.10, 3.11, or 3.12)
Graphviz (version 2.46 or later)
C/C++ Compiler

According to the docs:

Historically, installing Graphviz and PyGraphviz on Windows has been challenging. Fortunately, the Graphviz developers are working to fix this and their recent releases have much improved the situation. For this reason, PyGraphviz 1.7 only supports Graphviz 2.46.0 or higher on Windows. We recommend either manually installing the official binary release of Graphviz or using Chocolatey, which has been updated to Graphviz 2.46.0. You may also need to install Visual C/C++, e.g. from here. Assuming you have Python and Visual C/C++ installed, we believe the following should work on Windows 10 (64 bit) using PowerShell.

Manual download

Download and install 2.46.0 for Windows 10 (64-bit): stable_windows_10_cmake_Release_x64_graphviz-install-2.46.0-win64.exe.
Install PyGraphviz via


PS C:\> python -m pip install --config-settings="--global-option=build_ext" `
              --config-settings="--global-option=-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include" `
              --config-settings="--global-option=-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib" `
              pygraphviz

Chocolatey
PS C:\> choco install graphviz
PS C:\> python -m pip install --config-settings="--global-option=build_ext" `
              --config-settings="--global-option=-IC:\Program Files\Graphviz\include" `
              --config-settings="--global-option=-LC:\Program Files\Graphviz\lib" `
              pygraphviz

If you're still having issues with Windows, you can install Linux on Windows with WSL and use this package in that environment.
